# SQL Cop - test all the databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, unit-testing

We are implementing tSQLt as our SQL unit test framework. As such, we are also examining SQL Cop.

We have 8 databases. SQL Cop is nice in that they are prebuilt database checks. If we add tSQLt and SQL Cop to a database, everything works nicely.

However, we would like to separate our SQL Cop tests into a TestAllDatabases database.

**QUESTION: Is there a way to run SQL Cop tests from this database which is able to check all 8 of our  databases?**

For example, on SQL Server, we might have:

CustomerDB
InventoryDB

TestCustomerDB (holds tSQLt and all unit tests to run against CustomerDB)
TestInventoryDB (holds tSQLt and all unit tests to run against InventoryDB)
TestAllDatabasesDB (holds tSQLt and SQL Cop, but we need SQL Cop to check the other 3 databases. As is, it will only run checks within the TestAllDatabasesDB database).

Here's the code for SQL Cop which checks for store procs that begin with 'sp_%'. **Is there a way to modify this code to run the check against all databases on our SQL Server?** For example, how do we run this from TestAllDatabases and have it check CustomerDB? Whatever the answer is, we can then repeat this code to check InventoryDB. The idea is to have all the SQL Cop code in one location instead of having to replicate the code within each Testxxx database.

```
SELECT  @Output = @Output + SPECIFIC_SCHEMA + '.' + SPECIFIC_NAME + Char(13) + Char(10)
From    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
Where   SPECIFIC_NAME COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI LIKE 'sp[_]%'
        And SPECIFIC_NAME COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI NOT LIKE '%diagram%'
        AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA <> 'tSQLt'
Order By SPECIFIC_SCHEMA,SPECIFIC_NAME
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. In the FROM line, just change it to CustomerDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES ...

Comment: Have you checked out the sys catalog views?  INFORMATION_SCHEMA is not as reliable and is being phased out by most developers.

Comment: @TTeeple is there anything you can share that backs your opinion on INFORMATION_SCHEMA? I have never heard that it was unreliable. It doesn not show objects that are not part of the ANSI SQL-92 standard, but that does not mean that it is unreliable.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand is my go to source on these sort of things: https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Create 
Table   #Temp(
            DBName VarChar(100), 
            CheckDate DateTime, 
            CheckName VarChar(100), 
            Results VarChar(100))

exec sp_msforeachdb '
If ''?'' Not In (''Master'',''Model'',''msdb'',''TempDB'')
Insert Into #Temp(DBName, CheckDate, CheckName, Results)
SELECT  ''?'' As DBName, 
        GetDate(), 
        ''SP Name'', 
        SPECIFIC_SCHEMA + ''.'' + SPECIFIC_NAME + Char(13) + Char(10)
From    [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
Where   SPECIFIC_NAME COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI LIKE ''sp[_]%''
        And SPECIFIC_NAME COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI NOT LIKE ''%diagram%''
        AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA <> ''tSQLt''
Order By SPECIFIC_SCHEMA,SPECIFIC_NAME'

Select * From #Temp
Drop Table #Temp
```

If you copy/paste the code shown above in to a query window and run it, you will see that it generates a temp table and dumps the SQLCop check results in to it.  Long term, I would suggest that you create a real table in your TestAllDatabasesDB to store this information.

Note that the code, as is, will ignore the 4 system databases.  You may not want to ignore the model database if you are actually using this database as a model for new databases that are created.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you G Mastros. Your code is great. I modified it to make it into a SQL test and all the error procs get collected and outputs nicely using SQL Test.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @Count INT
    DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(MAX)
    CREATE TABLE #Temp (
          DBName VARCHAR(100) ,
          CheckDate DATETIME ,
          CheckName VARCHAR(100) ,
          Results VARCHAR(100)
        )

    SET @Output = 'These proc names should not begin with SP_: ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

    EXEC sp_msforeachdb '
        If ''?'' Not In (''Master'',''Model'',''msdb'',''TempDB'')
        Insert Into #Temp(DBName, CheckDate, CheckName, Results)
        SELECT  ''?'' As DBName, 
                GetDate(), 
                ''SP Name'', 
                SPECIFIC_SCHEMA + ''.'' + SPECIFIC_NAME + Char(13) + Char(10)
        From    [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
        Where   SPECIFIC_NAME COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI LIKE ''sp[_]%''
                And SPECIFIC_NAME COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI NOT LIKE ''%diagram%''
                AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA <> ''tSQLt''
        Order By SPECIFIC_SCHEMA,SPECIFIC_NAME'

    --SELECT  *
    --FROM    #Temp

    SELECT @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp);

    IF ( @Count > 0 ) 
        BEGIN -- run through cursor to grab all the violations
            DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(50)
            DECLARE @Proc VARCHAR(50)               

            DECLARE error_cursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT DBName, Results
            FROM #Temp

            OPEN error_cursor

            FETCH NEXT FROM error_cursor
            INTO @DBName, @Proc

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @Output = @Output + ' ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @DBName + '.' + @Proc;
                FETCH NEXT FROM error_cursor
                INTO @DBName, @Proc
            END

            CLOSE error_cursor
    DEALLOCATE error_cursor
            EXEC tSQLt.Fail @Output;

        END

    DROP TABLE #Temp
```